# How to test for a home bias in a data set?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, group-differences

I'm trying to think how I can test a data set I have, for transactions between buyers and sellers, for a home bias. My hypothesis is that buyers would rather buy from a merchant from their home country (and that merchants don't necessarily care to whom they sell, as long as they make a sale).

So, let's suppose there are:
$m$ sellers, 
$n$ buyers (let's assume $m < n$ for convenience), 
and $x$ different countries.
Each buyer buys one unit of the product, which is exactly the same for each seller.

Also let's assume that a buyer with a home bias would rather buy from a seller from his own country, and if there is no home bias the buyer is indifferent between the sellers (uniform distribution).

I thought about doing a $\chi^2\mathrm{-test}$, but the thing is that if there are many countries, and we assume that the difference would be for just one country, than the $\mathrm{d.f.}$ would rise and so the critical value, and we won't be able to find an effect.

For example, there are a total of $61$ countries, we'd expect $100$ purchases from each.
One country has $160$ purchases and the other $60$ have $99$,
the $\mathrm{d.f.}$ is $60$, and the critical value at the $95\%$ confidence level is ~$79$. The $\chi^2$ value is $36.6$, so we won't find a statistically significant difference.

I hope I'm clear about my problem.

Would love to hear your thoughts.

Thank you

Comment: I wonder if it would not be better to transform your problem to be more appropriate for your question. I mean instead of countries to have: home-country, foreign-country, availability-in-home-country, all as binary variables.

Comment: thanks for the comment. can you elaborate?

Comment: If you not inference for each country, but globally if the client bought something from a vendor from the same country as him or not, you might simplify. So, for each purchase you would have a binary field home-country with value 1 if it is the same country for the vendor and buyer, and 0 if not, and a binary field available-home, if there is a local vendor in the buyer's country to buy from (now I see that foreign-country is redundant). So, now, instead of having two factors with 61 levels each, you would have only 2 levels home-country x 2 levels for available-home.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit reluctant to take that approach because of the data lost. For instance, there might be a different effect going on, but by grouping the Rest Of World countries together, the differences between them wouldn't play a part and disappear. We might not catch another effect / the real effect.